Are wood stain and polyurethane all I need?
I wanted to replace about 10 pieces of top nail oak floors and bought about 10 pieces of red oak plywoods. If I want to alter the color of the red oak flooring, are  wood stain and polyurethane all I need? I have seen wood conditioners and wood finish and sealers, but I'm not sure if I need those too.

Hi, welcome to StackExchange. If you'll be sticking around and asking further questions, please note that it's one query per Question to focus Answers tightly on one topic as much as possible. "If I want to alter the color of the red oak flooring, are wood stain and polyurethane all I need?" On paper yes, but in practice it might not be as simple as that because wood colour can vary enormously, plus other factors that could make colour matching tricky — we have previous Q&As that touch on this, search for them for more detail (the internal search is excellent, you'll find them no problem).

Do also note that standard hardwood plywoods and laminated floor products are by no means equivalent. The surface veneers on much modern plywood is very thin as a rule, while on flooring products it's thick to very thick (to allow for sanding X number of times in the future).

@graphus is so right about the thin veneers on modern plywood.  It's almost to the point you can't sand them before applying a first stain/finish.  I've broken through the modern plywood veneers when refinishing something. I'm ranting about this while sitting at my computer desk where the surface top stain under the mouse is noticeably worn.  Fortunately this laminated wooden desktop was built in the early 1980s.

To the OP: can you include a picture of what you've bought as a replacement? I have a feeling that it's what we'd call an engineered floor, and it might already have its own finish, which could complicate matters.

Yes, stain and polyurethane will work for changing the color and protecting your red oak. But if you want a smoother finish, especially with oak, using a wood conditioner before staining can help prevent uneven blotches. Polyurethane acts as both a finish and sealer, so you’re set with just that after staining. You don’t need extra sealers unless you're after something specific. Happy refinishing!

Why especially with oak, which isn't known for blotching??

Even though oak isn't as prone to blotching as some other types of wood, like pine or cherry, it can still absorb stain unevenly due to its open grain structure.

Er, no. Oak doesn't absorb unevenly for that reason. My questions was why say especially with oak. Putting it that way suggests "uneven blotches" are not just known in oaks but a common thing, when that's simply not the case — oaks are on the other hand noted for how well they stain, very much the opposite of what you've intimated.
